# Unable to handled dynamic cookie value from request

Tags: jmeter

Please help me to get out from this issue.

- Added `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to `user.properties` file
- Restarted JMeter to pick the property up
- Accessed the cookie value as `${COOKIE_WRAPv0.8}`

but got below error.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 55: 
https://sqa-web.molace-pcc.net/Ref/DashBoard?WRAPv0.8=${COOKIE_WRAPv0.8} at
java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source) at
java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source) at
java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source) at
java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source) at
java.net.URI. (Unknown Source) at
java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:357) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178) at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491) at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425) at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you show your http request configuration and in View Results Tree show the response headers and cookies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that you have added a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in your test plan.

But I tested your site , there is no cookie except this one:

> COOKIE_ApplicationGatewayAffinity

As a consequence, COOKIE_WRAPv0.8 variable is not defined which leads to your issue

Comment: Thanks.. could you please tell me how to define COOKIE_WRAPv0.8 variable.

Comment: you can’t define it if the server does not send it. if server does, it will be defined.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you cookie value is not passing through properly. I have used a local variable as cookie and pass in your request. It went successfully. But, if I change the variable name or delete it..then I am getting the same error as you are.

As you can see below, the first request is good if the value is passing correctly.
But, the second request will give the same error, if the cookie value is not passing.

[image]

Hope this helps.